# How to match a 9 or 14 digits long number with regex?

Tags: regex

I need to check by Regex expression if 9 or 14 digits are typed.

The expression `\d{9}|\d{14}` seems to be not working properly, what's wrong ?

Comment: In what way is it not working properly?

Comment: That regex should work fine.  It's likely the way you are using it that is wrong.  Care to post more details?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This regex should work.

```
^(\d{9}|\d{14})$
```

Could you post the piece of code you're using and tell us what language are you using?
If you're using regex chances are that you have a string, and I'm sure your language has something to count string length.

EDIT:
as Rubens Farias pointed out in comments maybe ^...$ is needed because your regex would match any number with more than 9 digit as that number has a substring with a 9 digit long number.

Anyway check if you can do it with your language's string's methods/functions

Comment: maybe you should to use ^..$, to match entire input text.

Comment: While `^(\d{9}|\d{14})$` regex works fine with Java or JavaScript, it totally doesn't work for XSD. It kept matching only the first element of the `or` expression (XSD also can't contain anchors, since it implicitly anchors the entire expression) - any amount of digits different to 9 was regarded as invalid.
Made it work using the following regex - `\d{9}(\d{5})?`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
^(?:\d{9}|\d{14})$
```

Explanation:

```
^       - Start anchor
(?:     - Start of non-capturing group      
 \d{9}  - 9 digits
 |      - alternation
 \d{14} - 14 digits
)       - close of the group.
$       - End anchor
```

alternatively you can do:

```
^\d{9}(?:\d{5})?$
```

which matches `9` digits followed by optional `5` digits.

Answer (score -1):

```
(\d{9}|\d{14}) should work
```